# Angular2 how to get audio from backend with jwt

Tags: angular, html5-audio

please could somebody know how to get audio file from Spring backend using JWT.

```
 <audio controls preload="none">
                      <source src="http://localhost:8080/url/getRecord/recordname" type="audio/wav">

                    </audio>
```

but audio tag get request to backend without Authorization: Bearer , how can I add Authorization header to request of the html5 audio tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can add token into URL parameter and use token like cookie. I'm not sure how you can configure your backend like this but with .net core it is possible. Here is my application which use this https://github.com/JanneHarju/MultiSourcePlayList/blob/master/angular2App/app/modules/player/player.component.html
You can find one audio element there.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, you code not very usefull, because my API is use JWT authorization, that send header: Authorization: Bearer <token> for every request after first login, so I need to add header, not request param.

Comment: Yes I'm also using token in header in normal cases but I didn't found any other way to do this with audio element. In my application there is configured bearer authentication with header and cookie authentication when token is sent in URL parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I've added to my Spring JWT filter handle url params for that request.